# Passing blocks of code to functions/function pointers JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters, function-pointers

I have a `function` that has a couple of `for` statements in it. I need to be able to pass code to the for statements via parameters.

```
var a = function(paramCode){
    for(var eachRow=0; eachRow<20; eachRow++){
        for(var eachCol=0; eachCol<20; eachCol++){
            paramCode
        }
    }
}

a({ //the code I want to pass is surrounded in the function pointers
    if(array[x][y]){
        //do something
    }
});
```

This is a basic version of what I'm trying to do. The only problem is the error I get in the console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

I would love to know how to fix this error, or a way that I can still do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), this is a function which is handed over to the calling function as parameter.

```
var a = function (callback) {
        for (var eachRow = 0; eachRow < 20; eachRow++) {
            for (var eachCol = 0; eachCol < 20; eachCol++) {
                callback(array, eachRow, eachCol);
            }
        }
    };

a(function (array, x, y) {
    if (array[x][y]){
        //do something
    }
});
```